# Uncaught ReferenceError: canceled is not defined at deposit_list.php:40

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-select

```js
var x = <?php echo $row['type'];?>;
    if (x=="canceled") {
        document.getElementById("3").selected = "true";
    }else if (x=="pending") {
        document.getElementById("1").selected = "true";
    }else if (x=="succeed") {
        document.getElementById("2").selected = "true";
    }else{

    }
```

```html
<th><select id="select">
             <option value="1" id="1">Pending</option>
             <option value="2" id ="2">Succeed</option>
             <option value="3" id="3">Canceled</option>
</select></th>
```

When I run above code.. I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: canceled is not defined at deposit_list.php:40`. In 40 no. line it is indicating `<option value="2" id ="2">Succeed</option>`. I am unable to understand why this is happening?

Comment: @brombeer [Problem solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66901091/15449989). And, that's a JS code inside a `.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use "

```
var x = "<?php echo $row['type'];?>";
```

Comment: Worked.........!Unable to accept answer in 9 minutes. :(